# Vba code for overduedate cell coloring in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to set up vba code that will check if date is overdue and color the cell coressponsivle, but i cant make it work automaticaly on openninf file, it only works on change..
Any suggestions?

I tryed this code but i suppose somethings is off with it..

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ' Call the Worksheet_Change event to apply initial formatting

    Sheet1_WorksheetChange ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2023").Range("E11:E" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2023").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)

End Sub

 

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Check if the changed range intersects with the date column

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E11:E" & Me.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then

        Sheet1_WorksheetChange Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E11:E" & Me.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row))

    End If

End Sub

 

Private Sub Sheet1_WorksheetChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range

   

    ' Loop through each cell in the changed range

    For Each cell In Target

        ' Check if the date is overdue (today or earlier)

        If cell.Value <= Date Then

            ' Color the cell red

            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red

        ElseIf cell.Value <= Date + 14 And cell.Value > Date + 7 Then

            ' Color the cell orange

            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0) ' Orange

        ElseIf cell.Value <= Date + 7 Then

            ' Color the cell yellow

            cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Yellow

        End If

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: If I where you, I would use conditional formatting for that

Comment: Yea , i will probs do it this way...wanted to make it harder for me beacuse of...well who knows...thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all of those macros in the `Sheet1` code? A `Workbook_Open()` macro should be in the `ThisWorkbook` code. A `Worksheet_Change()` macro should be in the code of the whichever sheet you want it to run on.

[image]

Comment: Ahhaa, did not know that, i am fairly bad with vba , just managing things with google and chatgpt..thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by [FunThomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599798/funthomas), you can easily do this using conditional formatting, like in this example:

[image]

In order to get this done, I've applied highlighting rules, and used "Manage rules" in order to create a hierarchy in them (see "Stop if true" button).

Comment: Probably will do like this, as mentioned above by another persone...thanks!!(ps. How can i place this problem as solved?)

Comment: @jormungandr: you already have marked this problem as solved, when you accepted an answer.